# Ember.js How to access the whole object selected from Ember.Select?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have the following content for my select options in my controller:

```
opts: [
    {id: 1, code: 'TEST A', desc: 'DESC A', other: 'EXAMPLE A'},
    {id: 2, code: 'TEST B', desc: 'DESC B', other: 'EXAMPLE B'},
    {id: 3, code: 'TEST C', desc: 'DESC C', other: 'EXAMPLE C'}
],
v: 2,
```

And this is in my application.hbs

```
{{view Ember.Select
    content=opts
    optionValuePath='content.id',
    optionLabelPath='content.code'
    value=v}}
```

This renders the `select` element with `TEST B` as pre-selected.

#### Question

How do I get the whole object whenever I select a value from the list?
I understand I can get the value through `this.get('v')` which returns the value of the select element. Is there a way to get the other properties in the selected object?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You van bind to the selection which gives you the object itself

```
{{view Ember.Select
    content=opts
    optionValuePath='content.id'
    optionLabelPath='content.code'
    value=v
    selection=foo}}

this.get('foo');

this.get('foo.id');
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/quhov/1/edit